# Getting compilation error ORACLE

Tags: oracle

[New code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCbeH.png) I'm trying to code a trigger that doesn't allow duplicate values to ensure a band isn't playing at the same time. I get the below compilation error and can't figure it out:

[image]

Pretty new to oracle, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mysql, pls be careful with tagging!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you do not need a trigger to prevent duplicate records to be inserted. Create a [unique index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11724) on `band_playing` and `play_time` fields and this will take care of any duplicate records.

Regarding the error message: an `insert` statement creates a new record, therefore there is no `:old` version of the record, only a `:new` one. You would need to execute a `select` to check if a row with the same values exist in the table. Also, as @Littlefoot noted in his comment, an `if` must be closed by an `end if;` statement, which is missing from your code.